# Javascript - Handling a AJAX call response from a web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, object

I'm using Javascript and Jquery to call a web service.  The service should return an object.  If the object returned contains Result=0, I want to show an alert, and if it doesn't, I want to show a different alert.

My code is shown below.  I've tried "if (data.Result)" and "if (data.Result=0)", and neither of them work and show the "stock added" popup message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Object returned:

```
data: Object
Booking: Object
BookingId: "28eec5f6-29a7-e411-941a-00155d101201"
BookingProductIds: null
BookingStatus: 2
CrossSellProducts: null
ErrorMessage: ""
Result: 0
```

Javascript code:

```
    function generateOrder() {
        ABC.TixService.AddStockProduct(null, null, productRequest, ticketingRequest, function (context, data) {
            if (data.Result) {
                alert("stock added");
            }
            else
                alert("error");
        });



AddStockProduct: function (context, bookingId, productRequests, request, action) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'TixService.svc/AddStockProduct',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ bookingId: bookingId, productRequests: productRequests, request: request }),
        context: { context: context, action: action },
        success: function (data) {
            this.action(this.context, data.AddStockProductResult);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            ErrorResponse(xhr, thrownError);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: So, you always get the alert('error') correct?

Comment: `if (data.Result)` will be false if `data.Result` equals 0, and `if (data.Result=0)` will always be false because you used the assignment operator rather than the equal to operator and `0` is falsey.

Comment: @KevinB Yes. Result: 0 is what I expect to receive back.  If that is the case, I was to output "stock added", else "error". At the minute, I always get "error".

Comment: Have you tried `data.Result == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the test be:

```
 if(data.Result === 0){
     alert('stock added');
 }
```

Comment: I don't know. After reading the comments. if(!data.Result) ... if(data.Result == 0) and if(data.Result === 0) all work.

Comment: look up the === operator.  It is for exact matches.